# Twig why doesn't this work?

Tags: if-statement, twig

Why doesn't this work?

```
{% if theme.body_google_webfonts != ('Arial') or ('Verdana') %}
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family={{ theme.body_google_webfonts | url_encode }}:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
{% endif %}
```

If I choose font family arial or verdana the code still makes a google webfont request. If I choose any other font then nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shoot you should do it this way:

```
{% if theme.body_google_webfonts != ('Arial') and theme.body_google_webfonts != ('Verdana') %}
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family={{ theme.body_google_webfonts | url_encode }}:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
{% endif %}
```

So basically you need to use `and` operator and not `or`

Now if you have 2 conditions with or, if font is Verdana the whole expression will be true, because font is different than Arial, the same if Arial is sed the whole expression will be true because font is different than Verdana

Comment: Nabialek: That makes perfect sense! And offcourse I couldn't figure that out myself...